# Criar link para download de uma gravação de áudio

Tags: javascript

Peguei um [**exemplo na net em JavaScript**](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) que captura o áudio do dispositivo e com um botão na página é possível gravar o áudio e exportar o mesmo:

Neste código segue temos os botões:

```
<button onclick="startRecording(this);">record</button>
<button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>stop</button>
```

A partir deles vai comando para `startRecording` para iniciar a gravação

```
function startRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
}
```

e `stopRecording` para parar a gravação

```
function stopRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.stop();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Stopped recording.');

    // create WAV download link using audio data blob
    createDownloadLink();
    //recorder.clear();
  }
```

Nesta function tem uma chamada para a função `createDownloadLink()` que até onde entendi deveria criar um link para download do áudio gravado anteriormente
e ai esta o problema, o link não esta criando.

```
function createDownloadLink() {
  recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

Como habilitar o link para fazer o download do áudio quando clicar em Stop?

Comment: você já tem o base64 do arquivo gerado?

Comment: não tenho, como seria e pra que serve?

Comment: Qual o valor da var url? Você já tem ela? Se tiver basta criar uma tag a para realizar o download.

Comment: Debuguei agora e quando chega no 'stopRecording / createDownloadLink();'  nem entra na 'function createDownloadLink()'.    porém coloquei o mouse em cima do URL.cre... e aparece o caminho "http://localhost:59564/example_simple_exportwav.html" e o resultado deste link da erro: Causas mais prováveis:
* O diretório ou arquivo especificado não existe no servidor Web.
* A URL contém um erro tipográfico.
* Um filtro ou módulo personalizado, como URL Scan, restringe o acesso ao arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este repositório realmente está faltando alguns arquivos, e não ficaria viável colocar ele aqui. 
O repositório completo você pode encontrar [neste github](https://github.com/renilsonmeneguci/Recordmp3js).

E o tutorial completo de como utilizar, [você verá aqui](http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/).

Fonte: [NusoftHq](https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js) / [Audioec](http://audior.ec/).

> Utilizando o Chrome 46 não funcionou em meu computador. Porém no firefox 42 funciona normalmente.

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado pela ajuda.